# rxjs 5.5 pipe fs readdir event

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, fs

I want to read directory using rxjs style but I can't get it to work

```
import { readdir } from 'fs';
import { bindNodeCallback } from 'rxjs/observable/bindNodeCallback'; 
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function test() {

  bindNodeCallback(readdir).pipe(
    tap((x: any) => console.log(x))
  ).subscribe();
}

test();
```

It seems that the `bindNodeCallback` is not pipable, any ideas?

*I am using rxjs@5.5.2*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass somehow the name of the directory you want to read.
BindNodeCallback returns a function which you have to call to get an observable.

If you use bindNodeCallback with readdir then you have to do something like

bindNodeCallback(readdir)(dirName).pipe(....)

where dirName is a string containing the name of the directory you want to read.

You may find some more details in this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c